# Cannot find the updated python module

Tags: python, numpy, miniconda

I have installed the latest version of Python numpy module but when i tried to look for the version of the new numpy module, it still shows me the old version.

```
sudo pip install 'numpy==1.9.0'

python -c "import numpy; print numpy.__version__"
1.8.2
```

Here are my Python and pip versions

```
python --version
Python 2.7.6

pip --version
pip 8.1.2
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python?

Comment: Do a `python --version` and `pip --version` and update your question with the results.

Comment: Yes. I have several versions of Python

Comment: When you did pip -- version, did it also include the "from /usr/local/..."?

Comment: My pip is not in /usr/local but in /opt/miniconda_install/bin/pip

Comment: `python -m pip install numpy`.

Comment: Another thing you can try is this: python -c "import numpy; print(numpy)". It will show you the path it's pulling from. Which will give you a clue on where it's at.

Comment: @Abdou Python 2.7.6 does not include the `pip` module.

Comment: Set up `pip` for that version of python and make a symbolic link of the executable to your `PATH` and call it something like `pip2` or `pip276`. Just a thought.

Comment: For this multiple versions scenario I'd recommend using `virtualenv`, you could avoid this and any further problem regarding versioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `pip` you are using is not associated with the version of Python you're using. `pip` is installing NumPy into the miniconda distribution (BTW, are you aware that the latest version of NumPy is 1.11.3?), whereas your Python binary is reading its site-packages from elsewhere. To determine this, run

```
python
```

at the command prompt, then once in the interpreter run

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp # makes reading the results easier
>>> pp(sys.path)
```

`sys.executable` will tell you which `python` binary you're running, and the `sys.path` list will tell you from where Python is importing its packages.

All this being said, you need to point your `pip` script to the version of Python you're actually using. The easiest way (IMO) is to download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), then run either

```
python get-pip.py
```

(after changing to the download directory) or

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

depending on whether you're an admin or not. This will install the latest version of pip (currently 9.0.1) and associate it with the version of Python that was used to call the script.

Comment: It worked great. It was able to uninstall the old pip and the new installed pip was able to install the new numpy module. Thanks